# Did my union work?

Tags: mysql, join, union

We are in the process of making a in school version of Facebook aka Tigerbook now. We have created the following three data tables.

Users:

```
user    name
1       Hallie  
2       Dylan
3       Sarina
4       Dominic
```

Friends:

```
user    friend
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       1
3       1
4       1
2       4
4       2
3       2
2       3
```

Posts:

```
user    postid  post
1       101     This is TigerBook!
2       102     I am pregnant.
1       103     I like peeps
4       104     Giant Buzz Lightyears rock.
3       105     Die Tucker die
1       106     Murhur de derpity derp
2       107     banana spaghetti squid
4       108     chicken
```

We just used the syntax of:

```
select user from users union select user from friends union select user from posts;
```

And it came up with this:

```
user
1
2
1
4
```

All we were wondering was if the join worked or if we should try something else. We've already tried left joins and full joins, but nothing has worked very well.

And on a side note: when we connect the php code to the web page will it automatically generate users when they create a login or do we already have to create the users before they make the login?

Comment: Fear, Mark Z., they're coming !  What do you mean by "if the join worked" ? What do you wanna achieve ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that statement? Are you using foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's clearly not a `JOIN`... it's a `UNION` that removed duplicates of `user` across all three tables.. So to answer your question, your `UNION` worked. If you want to `JOIN` users to posts, you would need something like

```
SELECT a.user, a.name, b.postid, b.post
FROM users a
JOIN posts b ON b.user = a.user
```

This produces

```
| USER |    NAME | POSTID |                        POST |
---------------------------------------------------------
|    1 |  Hallie |    101 |          This is TigerBook! |
|    2 |   Dylan |    102 |              I am pregnant. |
|    1 |  Hallie |    103 |                I like peeps |
|    4 | Dominic |    104 | Giant Buzz Lightyears rock. |
|    3 |  Sarina |    105 |              Die Tucker die |
|    1 |  Hallie |    106 |      Murhur de derpity derp |
|    2 |   Dylan |    107 |      banana spaghetti squid |
|    4 | Dominic |    108 |                     chicken |
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ea19/1)

Comment: We know that it isn't a join, we were just saying that we had tried one before and it had not ultimately worked. As for the code you just gave me, that worked. But how would we get that joined with friends as well so that it will post to those friends?

Comment: @JohnAdams Right now there's no relationship between the posts and what friend it goes to. You need to have a from/to for the messages.

Comment: It's not supposed to go to a friend, but it's supposed to post on the certain person's web page. We want to display all the posts from all of YOUR friends rather than everyone on the whole websites posts. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: @JohnAdams That's really out of scope of this question. I suggest that you create a new question. Make sure you include the sample data (as you did here) and a desired result set and of course, what you've tried.